# Kotlin generic factories

Tags: kotlin, generics, types, factory

I'm trying to create an `AnimalFactory` that returns generic factories for making different types of `Animal`s, depending on the arguments passed to the `AnimalFactory`.

Here's the code:

```
interface Animal {
    fun talk(): String
}

class Cow: Animal {
    override fun talk(): String {
        return "mooo"
    }
}

class Cat: Animal {
    override fun talk(): String {
        return "miow"
    }
}

class Dog: Animal {
    override fun talk(): String {
        return "bark"
    }
}

object AnimalFactory {
    fun <T: Animal> AnimalMakerFactory(type: String): AnimalMaker<T> {
        val maker = when (type) {
            "cat" -> CatMaker()
            "dog" -> DogMaker()
            else -> CowMaker()
        }
        
        return maker
    }
}

interface AnimalMaker<out T: Animal> {
    fun make(): T
}

class CatMaker: AnimalMaker<Cat> {
    override fun make(): Cat {
        return Cat()
    }
}

class DogMaker: AnimalMaker<Dog> {
    override fun make(): Dog {
        return Dog()
    }
}

class CowMaker: AnimalMaker<Cow> {
    override fun make(): Cow {
        return Cow()
    }
}
```

I get a type exception:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: AnimalMaker<T>
Found: AnimalMaker<Animal>
```

I thought that AnimalMaker would solve this, but apparently not. Why is `AnimalMaker<T>` not of type `AnimalMaker<Animal>` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of the function is `AnimalMaker<T>` and not `AnimalMaker<Animal>` because that’s what you declared as the return type. The variable `maker` is indeed an `AnimalMaker<Animal>` but that isn’t a match for what the function is supposed to return because T could be a subtype of Animal.

You declared your function as having a generic type of `T: Animal`. Generic types are always an input to the function. In this case, it doesn’t make sense to use a generic input to the function because there’s no way to enforce that the type given is a match for the input String it corresponds with. To make your function work, you can remove `<T : Animal` and declare that it returns `AnimalMaker<Animal>`.

A little more explanation. There are two reasons why you might want to use generics in a function signature.

1. Enforce input parameter types.
2. Determine the output type.

You might use generics for one or both reasons (but the second can only be done by itself in a useful way by using reified generics, except in very specific cases where the returned class won’t be producing anything).

In your case, your input generic is not used to enforce the input parameter since that is just a String. To use it for the second reason, you would have to cast your return value’s type to the unknown (to the compiler) type T which would be unsafe because there’s no way to know if the input type given at the call site is a valid match for the given input String. And if you expected the call site to pass the right type, it would be redundant and error prone to also require a matching String to be passed.

Edit:
If you know the input type at compile time, then you can do this with reified generics. Get rid of the String input. It would look like this:

```
object AnimalFactory {
    inline fun <reified T: Animal> AnimalMakerFactory(): AnimalMaker<T> {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return when (T::class) {
            Cat::class -> CatMaker()
            Dog::class -> DogMaker()
            Cow::class -> CowMaker()
            else -> error("No factory found for type ${T::class}.")
        } as AnimalMaker<T>
    }
}

// Example usage
val someCatFactory = AnimalFactory.AnimalFactoryMaker<Cat>()
val cat: Cat = someCatFactory.make()
```

Inside this function, it is up to you to match the types up correctly, or there will be a ClassCastException at runtime. It seems logically it should be able to automatically cast them, but the compiler isn't sophisticated enough (yet?).

Comment: Thing is, I want to be able to pass the resulting AnimalMaker<Cat> to other parts of the code, and work with Cats (and their specific methods), rather than with Animals. 
So is there any way I can make it work?

Comment: Not if you only know the types by String. Where are these string types coming from? If they come from user input or some arbitrary source at run time, there's no way your code can know what they are at compile time, so generics cannot help. If you do know what the animal type is at compile time, then it can be done with reified generics. I added an example.